# working of pg_switch_xlog() in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

My current time line id is 8. I have `archive_command` is simple cp command which copies transaction log to a location. 
When I issue `pg_switch_xlog()` command it is copying all the archive files with timeline id 8 to its previous timeline ids. As per my knowledge `pg_switch_xlog()` command should archive only one xlog file but in my case I see many files at destination location given in cp command of `archive_command` after issuing `pg_switch_xlog()` command only once. 
Please let me know if I am missing something here.

Comment: Details are needed, including but not limited to PostgreSQL logs, your `archive_command`'s logs, exact filenames, etc. Show us what you see.

Comment: archive_command='cp %p pg_xlog/archive_files/%f'

Comment: Filenames generated after invoking one single pg_switch_xlog(): 

-rw------- 1 postgres postgres 16777216 Oct 19 17:50 00000005000000000000000A
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres 16777216 Oct 19 17:56 00000005000000000000000B
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres 16777216 Oct 19 17:59 00000006000000000000000B
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres 16777216 Oct 19 17:59 00000007000000000000000C
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres 16777216 Oct 19 17:59 00000008000000000000000C